# Unable to access data in MVC using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table named **Employee** in my database PragimTech, and two classes **Employee** and **EmployeeContext** in my Models folder.
My connection string in web.config is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="data source=GAURAV-PC/SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=PragimTech; integrated security=SSPI"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

When I run my application, i recieve a **ProviderIncompatibleException** saying

> **The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string**

I am unable to find the bug. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF 4.1 exception  "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423278/ef-4-1-exception-the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifesttoken-string) Did you check all the questions and answers about this exception? I believe it's the EF exception with the most hits you'll get when searching for it.

Comment: Thanks mate. Just one more thing I need to ask: do i need to keep the properties of the Employee class with the same name as the columns of my table Employee?

Comment: No, you don't. You can map property names to column names (data annotations or Fluent API). Search for "Entity Framework Column attribute HasColumnName" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

[This topic could be helpfull for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423278/ef-4-1-exception-the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifesttoken-string)

Check your `InnerException` for more details about error.

Comment: Thanks mate. Just one more thing I need to ask: do i need to keep the properties of the Employee class with the same name as the columns of my table Employee?

Comment: If you're using `CodeFirst` EF, it is good practise to keep the same properties name as columns name, so answer is - yes. Of course you could change columns name with `DataAnnotations` or `FluentAPI`, but it is not necessary.