# Can't connect to MySql database with Entity Framework 6

Tags: mysql, database-connection, entity-framework-6, connection-string, dbcontext

Installed via NuGet: MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entities, MySql.Data.Entity.

Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="WhateverEntities" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;database=dbname;uid=root;password=pass" />
<connectionStrings>
```

...

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
<entityFramework>
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "WhateverEntities") {}
```

tried to add:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

and:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

got this error:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The provider did not return a
>   ProviderManifestToken string.

What's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF 4.1 exception "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423278/ef-4-1-exception-the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifesttoken-string)

Comment: @vdwijngaert: I checked that before and changed my password in config.inc.php (Xampp) with no success.

Comment: What does PHP and Apache have to do with this? You're running a windows server.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a MySql database on localhost powered by Xampp.

Comment: Config.inc.php is probably your phpmyadmin configuration file. You can't change your mysql password in there. Verify your username and password using the commandline application, or using phpmyadmin.

Comment: I did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20796340/4427688 . I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I changed the password in PhpMyAdmin as well and works like a charm. It was easy in the end, but I lost several hours with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It was a matter of password as vdwijngaert suggested. Changed it in PhpMyAdmin.